# Turning on management content types affect in progress Designer workflows?

Tags: content-type, designer-workflow

I have a list of equipment and a Designer workflow which waits until the equipment's Expiry Date and then sends an email to the person in the Owner field.

If I turn on management of content types (so I can add better suited columns to the different types of equipment in this list), will it affect the in progress expiry workflows?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As long as the columns that the workflow is consuming/populating are not used I don't see any issue. I suggest you try this in your development environment first but I don't think anything is going to break